# Ruby 1.9.1 flog gem parse error on value nil (tNL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing

We are using flog on a ruby 1.9.1 on rails project and while processing some code it quits raising the exception:

```
ruby/1.9.1/racc/parser.rb:349:in `on_error':  (Racc::ParseError)
parse error on value nil (tNL)
```

I've had previous problems with this related to flog not recognizing the new Ruby sintax, but I can't find where the problem lies now.

Any help on knowing what is originating the problem is welcome, I can't find a way to know on which line flog is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the syntax as I said.

So this problem arises when you have variables with default values before other variables while defining a method.

```
def par1, par2='false', par3
  ...
end
```

This is valid code in ruby 1.9.x but not in previous ruby versions and since flog has no ruby 1.9.x syntax support it will raise an exception. As with any other incompatible syntax.

So if you are using flog you will have to use the ruby 1.8 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know flog doesn't support Ruby 1.9 at all, it depends on ParseTree which [has been killed for 1.9](http://blog.zenspider.com/2009/04/parsetree-eol.html). Maybe you can try using something like https://github.com/hubertlepicki/metric_abc?

Comment: Thank you! I know that flog depends con ParseTree which has been killed for 1.9.
I had no hope in that matter, the answer I expected was a way to tell where the problem lied. Since ruby will execute just fine I needed to know what code was likely to produce the error. 
Thanks for the suggestion, I will see if I can convince the team to move to something totally ruby 1.9 compatible.